# merge keys no common value in python

Tags: python, merge, key

I'm trying to merge two data files product and review on common key "product_id" and it indicates there is no common value - therefore I get a merged table permeated by NaN.

After some examination, I found out that there are indeed common values.

code:
(for some weird reason, the name "product_id" on file product is '\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id')

```
product2=product[['\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id','page_id']].sort('\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id') 
review2=review[['product_id','review_id']]
tables=[product2,review2]
for item in tables:
    print item.head(5)
    print item.shape


      ﻿product_id  page_id
4028      1071569    39995
4435      1071570    42719
2519      1071571    27421
3992      1071572    39839
4018      1071574    39978
(4999, 2)
   product_id  review_id
0     1071569    1755406
1     1071569    1755407
2     1071569    1755408
3     1071569    1755409
4     1071569    1755410
(4999, 2)

product2["\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id"][4028]==review2['product_id'][0]
True
```

This simple examination reveals that at least 'product id' 1071569 exists in two tables.but whilst I tried:

```
product2["\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id"][4028] in review2['product_id']
```

it returns False.

Anybody can help me with that?

Comment: Not sure about your main question, but the '\xef\xbb\xbf' is because the file is a UTF-8 file, and you're likely opening it as an ASCII file.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it:

```
product2["\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id"][4028] in review2['product_id'].values
```

If it helps, you can visualise the `review2['product_id']` as a dictionary with they key being the line number `0`, `1`, `2`, `...` and the value being the corresponding `product_id on` that line number. So `product2["\xef\xbb\xbfproduct_id"][4028] in review2['product_id']` does not work because it searches for line number `1071569` which you fortunately do not have. If you had a bigger dataset this would return `True` but that would be a logic error because you are not checking for a line number but you are checking if  `product_id` of `product2` data frame is available as a product id of `reviews2` data frame regardless which line number it is on on `reviews2`.